# Facebook crawler user-agent match regular expression

Tags: regex, facebook, web-crawler

I am trying to create a regular expression for Facebook Crawler detection.  The FB Crawler uses one of following user-agent string.

- FacebookExternalHit\1.0
- FacebookExternalHit\1.1
- Facebot

This is the regular expression I created but my java code fails to do pattern match.

- ^FacebookExternalHit/.*?|Facebot/i

What changes I need to make for above reg-ex to work.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no forward slash after Hit. There is a backward slash.

Comment: Thanks WizKid. It did not make a difference. This is what I am using now.   ^FacebookExternalHit\/.*?|Facebot/i

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/wtvrUH/1

Comment: Yes, changed to 1.0. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, S.Kablar. This helped a lot. It does everything including case-insensitive search. But Java code does not honor case-insensitive search. This works on https://regex101.com/r/321RQ6/1 not in Java code. Any ideas?

Comment: Then you need to figure out how in Java how you turn on case insensitive check. We don't know your code or how you do regex checks in Java.

Comment: I solved it. Thanks S.Kablar. Here is expression I used for Java 8. In case anybody needs help in future. **(?i:\bFacebookExternalHit(?:\\1\.[0-9])?\b|\bFacebot\b)**